# Smart meters and filtering

Tags: meter

<del>My mother suffers from Electromagnetic hypersensitivity and her electricity provider recently installed her a HF Smart Meter (CERM 1).</del>

I've been researching about ways of filtering the dirty power created by the new smart meters. I came across a document ([link](http://www.eiwellspring.org/tech/FilteringNewSmartMeters.pdf)) mentioning a filter used by E.ON in Sweden, and it mentions one particular filter model, the  FN256,25A. Having little or no knowledge on electricity, I've been looking around for a shop that sells it and found this ([link](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/00a7/0900766b800a7bb8.pdf)).

It would be a big coincidence that they filter mentioned in the first link and the one in the second have the exact same model name/number but they are not the same machine, but even so, I'd be very grateful if somebody could confirm me that the Schaffner FN 256 Filter can indeed be user for filtering a Smart Meter "pollution".

Comment: What is "EHS"??

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_hypersensitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_hypersensitivity)

Comment: From that link you'll find that EHS is completely psychosomatic as sufferers can't tell the difference between real electromagnetic radiation or simulated emf. So basically, if you put some plastic on your meter, and tell her that you've added a filter, her problems will go away so long as she believes you.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question and to be honest, psychosomatic or not psychosomatic the symptoms are real. E.ON is providing filters, and some reason to do so might they have.

Comment: I never said the symptoms aren't real. I said, it doesn't matter which filter you buy; they should all work so long as she believes it works. E.ON is providing filters because people believe smart meters cause problems and they would like to placate their customer base regardless of the science behind it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because EHS is mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: Sounds like these devices are the equivalent of those magic rocks you put on top of your speakers to make them sound better...

Comment: But what about copper bracelets - surely they work to short out rf and prevent it burning the hairs on your arm? ;)

Comment: Being involved with smart meter design I have no idea where people come up with this crap ... a shunt, relay contact and voltage divider is all ... ffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Philosophy aside, yes, the Schaffner FN 256 Filter should attenuate signals by an order of about 100 by the time your frequency is up to 100 kHz. Above that frequency it generally attenuates the signal even more.

20 kHz you have about 1/3 of the signal.
40 kHz you have about 1/10 of the signal.
100 kHz you have about 1/100th.

So yes, it does reduce high frequency noise. Keep in mind normal power is transmitted at 50 - 60 Hz (about 3 orders of magnitude lower than where this starts to seriously attenuate).